# Wi-Fi Connection sharing on Macbook Air via USB dongle

Tags: wifi, internet-sharing

In my room I can only connect one device to the wifi router. In order to connect all my devices, I thought of connecting my macbook air to the router, then have a USB dongle connected to the macbook air, which would share the internet connection with the rest of my devices. Is this possible, and should the USB dongle have any particular features I need to look out for?

Comment: It's important to know which other devices you are talking about. Is it a printer, a computer, a networked harddisk? Could you add that to your answer?

Comment: Your question is very similar to this one:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83132/is-it-possible-to-jury-rig-internet-sharing-to-share-an-internet-connection-wire/83135#83135